# which API are more frequently used in underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

I have been told that underscore.js is helpful to my work, but there are so many API in underscore.js ,my question is which API are more frequently used?

Comment: There is only one API with many functions. Most frequently used are probably the iteration primitives `each`, `map` and `filter`, but I don't see why you would ask for commonness. Please ask a more specific question like "*How to solve [this problem] with the Underscore functions*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a **utility library for javascript**, which contains some helpful functions related to javascript.

From http://underscorejs.org/:

> `Underscore` is a utility-belt library for JavaScript that provides a lot of the functional programming support that you would expect in Prototype.js (or Ruby), but without extending any of the built-in JavaScript objects. It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux, and Backbone.js's suspenders